# Выполнить проверку в unity 3d

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Есть персонаж (2d), он умеет прыгать и бегать, но прыгает он может много раз из за того что нету проверки спрайта на котором он стоит.
Как перед прыжком проверить спрайт на котором он стоит и если он в воздухе то не прыгать?

Вот так не работает(самая новая версия юнити):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SimplePlatformController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    public float jumpForce = 700f;
    bool facingRight = true;
    bool grounded = false;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    public float move;

    // Use this for initialization
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (grounded && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
        }
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

        if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
            Flip();
        else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
            Flip();

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: По возможности, дайте какой-то мануал по написанию 2D игр на Unity 3D, буду очень благодарен!)

Comment: Можно проверить соприкается ли персонаж с коллайдером земли, но тогда это нагрузка на физику

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: @RomanKravets в `FixedUpdate` вы уже это делаете (правда не с коллайдером, а со слоем...но не суть).. Остальная проверка в коде прыжка. Но вы наверное боитесь показывать код, поэтому сказать в чем у вас ошибка можно только догадываться и гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не показал код, потому что я заходил с телефона и не было под рукой ноутбука, вот код - http://pastebin.com/NNkwTWrz

Comment: Ваш скрипт вполне рабочий. Вы что-то забыли сделать видимо... Например добавить объект `groundCheck` к своему спрайту или повесить на этот самый `groundCheck` коллайдер2D (если на самом игроке его нет и если чекер в этом нуждается) или забыли добавить коллайдер к земле..или забыли добавить маску для земли или забыли в `whatIsGround` выбрать землю, а там стоит `Everything` и поэтому у вас `grounded` всегда `false`............или  сделайте переменную `grounded` публично (или перейдите в режим Debug) и проследите когда она у вас становится true/false

Comment: Ну что, помогло хоть что-то из того, что я сказал?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшим решением для подобных ситуаций будет отказ от использования физики столкновений в сторону математики и `Raycast`. Физика в Unity является довольно ресурсоемкой вещью + сама Unity по умолчанию использует Box2d в случае в 2d физикой и работает с ней, как с черным ящиком. То есть если в расчетах самой физики что-то будет недостаточно точно для вас, то поправить это будет довольно сложно, а в некоторых случаях невозможно.

В отличии от функций поиска и проверки пересечений и коллизий с точки зрения производительности `Raycast` является довольно дешевой операцией. Подробней про `Raycast`можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).

Что касается прыжков в вашем случает, то будет самой хорошей практикой делать `Raycast` определенной длины в направлении пола и на основе этого делать вывод о том, находится ли персонаж в воздухе или на земле.

Серия довольно подробных туториалов на тему создания 2d платформера, в том числе полный разбор физики движения/прыжков/падений [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f0hqURlhyIoAabKPgRsqjz). Единственное, туториал на английском, но на простом и версия Unity там используется старенькая, и могут быть некоторые старые вызовы, которые выглядят по другому в более новых версиях Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через стайты в анимации. Т.е. если сейчас анимация падения или прыжка, переход в анимацию прыжок не возможен. А вот неплохой туторила https://habrahabr.ru/post/212309/

Comment: Только автор не это (как с одной анимации в другую перейти) спрашивает. Он спрашивает почему персонаж   прыгает не смотря на то, что персонаж в воздухе

Comment: Если грамотно сделать Animator в Unity, то им можно управлять состояниями героя. И прыжок не будет проходить в воздухе.

Comment: Структура (переходы между анимациями)  и инструменты работы с Animator позволяет сделать очень много, избегая костылей для кодирования этих вещей.